# Changes to Excel file not showing up in pandas ExcelFile() import

Tags: python, django, excel, pandas

I am using the code below to import data from and Excel file to a Django-based website. The file reads just fine but when I make changes to the file and save them and then reload my website, the data is not refreshed. But, if I save the modified Excel file that I'm trying to load under a different name and load that file instead, the website updates as it's supposed to. I would like for changes I make to show up without having to rename the file. How can I tell pandas to do this?

```
from pandas import *
xlsx = ExcelFile('Testbook3.xlsx')
df = xlsx.parse(xlsx.sheet_names[0])
df_dict = df.to_dict()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to re-read your Excel file in Pandas - it should be pretty straightforward:

```
df = pd.read_excel(r'/path/to/Testbook3.xlsx')
df_dict = df.to_dict()
```

or just:

```
df_dict = pd.read_excel(r'/path/to/Testbook3.xlsx').to_dict()
```

PS if it's a django issue, then i'm out of the game...

Comment: Thanks very much, Max. I tested this out and am still experiencing the same issues. I decided to test it in my command prompt and the data updates as its supposed to, which suggests that the problem is downstream from this script. When I run the server, the data updates correctly, but I don't want to have to do that each time. I should just be able to refresh the page and get the response I need. I know you said Django is outside your wheelhouse, so thank you for getting me a step closer!